# Excluding Specific Devices in iOS (Device Compatibility)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have an app that is optimised for A8 chips and above. Is there a way to specify this to ensure the compatibility list in the iTunes store is accurate?

Currently the only restriction added to `Info.plist` is `arm64`, but there's a few incompatible devices this lets through (http://iossupportmatrix.com)

[image: App Store Compatibility list]

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create conditionals based on UIDevice.current.model

Link to the documentation [UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice)